# jquery clone with HTML drop down option two drop down select the same value an alert should select different value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently working on jquery clone  where user click add it will clone the div perfectly but I have dropdown. If user select cellphone in drop down and in other dropdown if user select the same cellphone it should duplicate found and the dropdown value has to clear.

```
 $('.slt_major select option:selected').each(function(i, e) {
 alert("check");
    //Check if values match AND if not default AND not match changed item to self
    if ($(e).val() == cI.val() && $(e).val() != 0 && $(e).parent().index() != cI.index()) {

        alert('Duplicate found!');
        cI.val('0');
    }
});
```

I was not able to see where the error was even the alert was not generating. Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/k98pqtu4/).

Thanks.

Comment: "if user select the same cellphone", you mean select cell phone as an option? or also adds the same phone number in it?

Comment: sorry @psylogic because already user select the cellphone and in the new row  we don't want to one more cellphone to be select he has to select some other option

Comment: there's too much missing information to give a proper solution to your question. Please consider editing the question.

Comment: i guess the code which i provided it was correct code in fiddle so you want to change the heading here could you please suggest me what i have to gave

Comment: @Mahadevan Your clone is totally going to mess up since you are not updating `id`s thus creating duplicate `id` in your `html`

Comment: provide some information like all the selected options in the dropdown should have different values or something else?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao did you checked the fiddle link where I am using dynamically adding div id

Comment: Yea.. I checked the fiddle and then am telling you are just doing `this.id` in `$.each` after `clone`.. I am talking about all the `select` and other `elements` inside `added` row..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao can you please help me out here I was struggle with this please do the needful

Comment: Let me check.. Give me few moments..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here it is: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/k98pqtu4/7/)**

First I would like to correct your **adding part** since you were adding duplicate `id`s into internal `elements` of `cloned row`. So just change your code as below and check for inline comments.

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn_more", function () { 
        var $clone = $('.cloned-row:eq(0)').clone();
        $clone.find('[id]').each(function(){
            this.id=this.id +(count) //change the id of each element by adding count to it
        });
        $clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_less1 phn_del' value='Del' id='buttonless"+count+"'/>")
        $clone.attr('id', "added"+(count)); //just append count here
        $clone.find('.preferred').attr('checked', false);
        $clone.find('.sslt_Field').val(0);
        $clone.find('.txt_CC').val('');
        $clone.find('.txt_Pno').val('');
        $(this).parents('.em_pho').after($clone);
        count++; //increment count at the end.
});
```

Now to check for duplicate `options` you can do it as below. Also check inline comments:

```
//attach event handler to document since you need event delegation on dynamically created elements
//attach change event to class 'sslt_Field'
$(document).on('change','select.sslt_Field',function(event) {
    var cI = $(this); //store a reference
    var others=$('select.sslt_Field').not(cI);
    //store reference to other select elements except the selected one

    $.each(others,function(){
       //iterate through remaining selects 
       if($(cI).val()==$(this).val() && $(cI).val()!="")//check if value has been 
       //already selected on other select
       {
           $(cI).val('');//empty the value
           alert('already selected');//display alert.
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Tel me how you reproduced that @RaviKumar

Comment: add 4-5 times... and you get the error. http://jsfiddle.net/k98pqtu4/5/ check this

Comment: Come on!! Be clear with steps @RaviKumar.. I added 4 to 5 times and changed the values in new `select`.. its working fine..

Comment: Hmm... ok 1. Cellphone 2. Business 3. bank 4. blank 5. blank now change 5 to Business or cell phone then tell me how many times you get alert.

Comment: Oh yea.. Its checking for blank values too.. Anyways.. Thank you for pointing out.. Updating the answer.. @RaviKumar